# How does one browse a module's functions and their types?

Tags: haskell, module

How do Haskell programmers browse through a module to see the available methods and data types?

I am asking because i think that there is a faster and easier way then to always enter hoogle and look them up (as i am currently doing). I just want to see the methods and signatures.

**P.S** I discovered `GHCI` provides a `browse` method but is there any way to pipe the result in a file ? Redirecting ghci output to file ?

Comment: Is your question actually about how to pipe the output of `:browse` to a file? You know about haddocks, hoogle, `:browse`, etc. so it's not clear to me what kind of answer you're looking for. Maybe you want editor/IDE integration?

Comment: Well  i am a beginner in haskell and i wanted to know how can i easily check a module's interface..and see what methods it exposes , and their signatures.So yes one question would be how can i pipe the output of an `ghci` command like `browse` to a file.

Comment: `stack haddock --open`?

Comment: Usually when you "*browse through a module*" you already browse through its documentation, not through its code, so I'm not quite sure what you are asking for.

Comment: I want to know if there is anywhere where i can find the module with only its declared methods and definitions (like a header if you will).Something like lets say for `System.IO`  i would see `readFile::FilePath->IO String  ; writeFile::FilePath->String->IO() ...`etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a simple command line option and shell redirect?

```
ghci -e ':browse Prelude' > file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

My usual approach to this is finding the  package on Hackage and browsing the docs on there - which have the methods and signatures (types).

For example for `Data.List`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-List.html